# How do I return a proper success/error message for JQuery .ajax() using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I keep getting the error alert. There is nothing wrong with the MYSQL part, the query gets executed and I can see the email addresses in the db.

**The client side:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("form#subsribe_form").submit(function() {
      var email = $("#email").val();

      $.ajax({
        url: "subscribe.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {email: email},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
          alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**The server side:**

```
<?php 
$user="username";
$password="password";
$database="database";

mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$senderEmail = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['email'] ) : "";

if($senderEmail != "")
    $query = "INSERT INTO participants(col1 , col2) VALUES (CURDATE(),'".$senderEmail."')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();

$response_array['status'] = 'success';    

echo json_encode($response_array);
?>
```

Comment: Consider using pdo, mysql_ functions are obsolete

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You need to provide the right content type if you're using JSON dataType. Before echo-ing the json, put the correct header.

```
<?php    
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response_array);
?>
```

Additional fix, you should check whether the query succeed or not.

```
if(mysql_query($query)){
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';  
}else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';  
}
```

On the client side:

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
    }else if(data.status == 'error'){
        alert("Error on query!");
    }
},
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, and you should differentiate *server side error* and *transmission error*. I put the check on `success` part of the AJAX to check the value sent by server (so it is not transmission error).

Comment: how do store multiple varriable like $response_array['status']='success', $response_array['userid'] = $userid; etc.

Answer (score 35):

Just so you know, you can use this for debugging. It helped me a lot, and still does

```
error:function(x,e) {
    if (x.status==0) {
        alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
    } else if(x.status==404) {
        alert('Requested URL not found.');
    } else if(x.status==500) {
        alert('Internel Server Error.');
    } else if(e=='parsererror') {
        alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
    } else if(e=='timeout'){
        alert('Request Time out.');
    } else {
        alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pieter: Then implement your own js_encode :) Try this one : http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7487

Answer (score 24):

Some people recommend using HTTP status codes, but I rather despise that practice. e.g. If you're doing a search engine and the provided keywords have no results, the suggestion would be to return a 404 error.

However, I consider that wrong. HTTP status codes apply to the actual browser<->server connection. Everything about the connect went perfectly. The browser made a request, the server invoked your handler script. The script returned 'no rows'. Nothing in that signifies "404 page not found" - the page **WAS** found.

Instead, I favor divorcing the HTTP layer from the status of your server-side operations. Instead of simply returning some text in a json string, I always return a JSON data structure which encapsulates request status and request results.

e.g. in PHP you'd have

```
$results = array(
   'error' => false,
   'error_msg' => 'Everything A-OK',
   'data' => array(....results of request here ...)
);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Then in your client-side code you'd have

```
if (!data.error) {
   ... got data, do something with it ...
} else {
   ... invoke error handler ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to build an AJAX webservice, you need TWO files :

- A calling Javascript that sends data as POST (could be as GET) using JQuery AJAX
- A PHP webservice that returns a JSON object (this is convenient to return arrays or large amount of data)

So, first you call your webservice using this JQuery syntax, in the JavaScript file :

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'mywebservice.php',
     type : 'POST',
     data : 'records_to_export=' + selected_ids, // On fait passer nos variables, exactement comme en GET, au script more_com.php
     dataType : 'json',
     success: function (data) {
          alert("The file is "+data.fichierZIP);
     },
     error: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          var responseText=JSON.parse(data.responseText);
          alert("Error(s) while building the ZIP file:\n"+responseText.messages);
     }
});
```

Your PHP file (mywebservice.php, as written in the AJAX call) should include something like this in its end, to return a correct Success or Error status:

```
<?php
    //...
    //I am processing the data that the calling Javascript just ordered (it is in the $_POST). In this example (details not shown), I built a ZIP file and have its filename in variable "$filename"
    //$errors is a string that may contain an error message while preparing the ZIP file
    //In the end, I check if there has been an error, and if so, I return an error object
    //...

    if ($errors==''){
        //if there is no error, the header is normal, and you return your JSON object to the calling JavaScript
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        $result=array();
        $result['ZIPFILENAME'] = basename($filename); 
        print json_encode($result);
    } else {
        //if there is an error, you should return a special header, followed by another JSON object
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Booboo');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        $result=array();
        $result['messages'] = $errors;
        //feel free to add other information like $result['errorcode']
        die(json_encode($result));
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Server side:

```
if (mysql_query($query)) {
    // ...
}
else {
    ajaxError(); 
}
```

Client side:

```
error: function() {
    alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
},
success: function(){
    alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

adding to the top answer: here is some sample code from PHP and Jquery:

```
$("#button").click(function () {
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler.php",
            data: dataString,

                success: function(data) {

                  if(data.status == "success"){

                 /* alert("Thank you for subscribing!");*/

                   $(".title").html("");
                    $(".message").html(data.message)
                    .hide().fadeIn(1000, function() {
                        $(".message").append("");
                        }).delay(1000).fadeOut("fast");

                 /*    setTimeout(function() {
                      window.location.href = "myhome.php";
                    }, 2500);*/


                  }
                  else if(data.status == "error"){
                      alert("Error on query!");
                  }




                    }


        });

        return false;
     }
 });
```

PHP - send custom message / status:

```
    $response_array['status'] = 'success'; /* match error string in jquery if/else */ 
    $response_array['message'] = 'RFQ Sent!';   /* add custom message */ 
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was that my header type wasn't set properly.

I just added this before my json echo

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

...you may also want to check for cross site scripting issues...if your html pages comes from a different domain/port combi then your rest service, your browser may block the call.

Typically, right mouse->inspect on your html page.
Then look in the error console for errors like

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...:8080' from origin '...:8383' has been blocked by 
  CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
  resource.