# PHP variable to JS variable using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to convert a PHP variable to a JS variable so I can use it in a game I'm making. When I check the map code it is just `undefined`. Thanks in advance. FYI the PHP works.

```
<script>
    var mapCode;
    var used;
    var active;

    function downloadCode() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getMapCode.php',
            data: {
                mapCode: $mapCode,
                used: $used,
                active: $active,
            },
            dataType: "text",
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

```php
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "database";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
  mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) 
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  // echo "Connected successfully";

  $query = "SELECT mapCode FROM mapCodes";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $mapCode = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

  $query1 = "SELECT used FROM mapCodes";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
  $used = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);

  $query2 = "SELECT active FROM mapCodes";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
  $active = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);

  mysqli_close($conn);  
?>
```

I understand that the PHP Code is hideous but it works and I'm going to 'pretty it up' later when the whole thing is working

Comment: mapCode: <?=$mapCode;>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return a proper success/error message for JQuery .ajax() using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676084/how-do-i-return-a-proper-success-error-message-for-jquery-ajax-using-php)

Comment: This'll help: var mapCode="<?php echo isset($mapCode) && !empty($mapCode)?$mapCode:""?>";

Answer (score 1):

If the file extension is `.php` and not `.js` then this should work

```
<script>
    function downloadCode() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getMapCode.php',
            data: {
                mapCode: "<?php echo $mapCode; ?>",
                used: "<?php echo $used; ?>",
                active: "<?php echo $active; ?>",
            },
            dataType: "text",
        });
    }
</script>
```

If you have `.js` file then declare javascript variable before including your js in `.php` file

```
<script>
    var mapCode = "<?php echo $mapCode; ?>";
    var used = "<?php echo $used; ?>";
    var active = "<?php echo $active; ?>";
</script>
```

then in `.js` file you will get easily

```
<script>
    function downloadCode() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getMapCode.php',
            data: {
                mapCode: mapCode,
                used: used,
                active: active,
            },
            dataType: "text",
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, after a very long night of coffee i got this working with help from @Ultrazz008 thank you for the suggestion tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use <?php echo $mapCode;?> instead $mapCode. .... php variables can't be reed whithout open Php tag

Answer (score 0):

My current project is actually dealing with lots of ajax calls,
here is the simplified version of what I use to communicate with server:

```
// php
// needed functions
function JSONE(array $array)
{
    $json_str = json_encode( $array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
    if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        return $json_str;
    }
    throw new Exception(__FUNCTION__.': bad $array.');
}
function output_array_as_json(array $array)
{
    if (headers_sent()) throw new Exception(__FUNCTION__.': headers already sent.');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print JSONE($array);
    exit();
}

// pack all data
$json_output = array(
    'mapCode'   => $mapCode,
    'used'      => $used,
    'active'    => $active
);

// output/exit
output_array_as_json( $json_output );


// javascript
function _fetch()
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'getMapCode.php', // url copied from yours
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, req){
            console.log('server respond:', data);
            window.mydata = data;
        },
        error: function(req , textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("jqXHR["+textStatus+"]: "+errorThrown);
            console.log('jqXHR.data', req.responseText);
        }
    });
}

window.mydata = null;
_fetch();
```

I have not tested this, but let me know I'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

How did i get you, you need to get the result from ajax request, to do it, you should first setup your php outputs your results, so the ajax can get outputed results from php like this:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "database";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
  mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) 
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  // echo "Connected successfully";

  $query = "SELECT mapCode FROM mapCodes";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $mapCode = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

  $query1 = "SELECT used FROM mapCodes";
  $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
  $used = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);

  $query2 = "SELECT active FROM mapCodes";
  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
  $active = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);

  mysqli_close($conn); 
  // Outputing results:
  echo json_encode(array('mapCode'=>$mapCode[0], 'used'=>$used[0], 'active'=>$active[0]));
?>
```

Then in ajax, use `success` for listening return message after ajax finished:

```
<script>
    var mapCode;
    var used;
    var active;

    function downloadCode() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getMapCode.php',
            data: {
                /** Your data to send to server **/
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) { /** Here is data returned by php echo **/
                var temp = $.parseJSON(data);
                mapCode = temp['mapCode'];
                used = temp['used'];
                active = temp['active'];
            }
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but when I put this in the code I still get undefined as the map code. Thanks tho :)

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row` returns array, will change php output in 1 minute, check now

Comment: Did you tried now with outputing from php: `echo json_encode(array('mapCode'=>$mapCode[0], 'used'=>$used[0], 'active'=>$active[0]));`

Comment: ok i have to change $.parseJSON(data); to JSON.stringify(data); or else i get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 | and i just tried it and it made no difference

Comment: Check does your php returns some notice, because you turned on error logging, that's why can it happen.. Change `ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);` to `ini_set('display_errors', 0); 
  error_reporting(E_ERROR);`

Comment: Check does PHP returns data at all, use at javascript in success callback: `success: function(data) { alert(data) }` and see is anything returned from php..

Comment: yes it gives me a record of what I have on my database

Comment: But does it give anything else that could cause `$.parseJSON()` to fail in parsing.. Use `console.log(data);` and copy full output result from console window and post it here

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
{"mapCode":"12345","used":"No","active":"No"}</body>
</html>

Comment: Remove `HTML code` at all from PHP output, it should just output `{"mapCode":"12345","used":"No","active":"No"}` and it will work

Comment: i appreciate the help but its still not working :( is there anything else i need to look at?

Comment: Mate, did you get the output as i wrote, without any other characters, just the json string ? If you did, everything should be fine, check the fiddle if you got the data like I said: https://jsfiddle.net/jcvpw4uc/1/

Comment: thanks I got it working. Yea it was me, i had some things the wrong way around thanks so much :D and a nice day