# What's wrong with this json response?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I've copied the accepted answer to a question [How do I return a proper success/error message for JQuery .ajax() using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676084/how-do-i-return-a-proper-success-error-message-for-jquery-ajax-using-php)

My PHP script is returning the following json. The headers are correct: `Content-type: application/json` and `json_encode()` on the output in the PHP script:

```
{"success":"success"}
```

But the jquery to check the status isn't working:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/index',
        data: $("#NewsletterSignup").serialize(), 
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success == 'success') {
                console.log('successful');
            } else if(data.errors){
                console.log('error occurred');
            }
        }
    });
```

So I get the initial `console.log(data)` which gives `{"success":"success"}`. But then it's not evaluating the `if...else if` condition. Why?

jquery version is 1.12.3

Comment: You have not specified `dataType:"JSON"` in your ajax code

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it.

Comment: or add `header('Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');` to your `PHP` file

Comment: @DarkBee that was already there. The issue was with the `dataType` missing in my js.

Comment: Then you did something wrong as `Jquery.ajax` is able to guess the correct datatype

Comment: @DarkBee, that's what I thought as well, which is why I overlooked it. However, this does indeed fix the problem for me.

Comment: Anyway it got solved for you in the end. That's what matters the most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add dataType to your ajax code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax/index',
    data: $("#NewsletterSignup").serialize(), 
    dataType:'json,'    //  CHECK THIS....
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.success == 'success') {
            console.log('successful');
        } else if(data.errors){
            console.log('error occurred');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This was the issue. The PHP script providing the response was already sending the correct json headers. The issue was `dataType:` missing in my js.

Comment: Thank you @Andy for accepting the answer. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

From php file you need to encode it as

```
json_encode({"success":"success"});
```

And should expect `dataType:'json'`

Answer (score 0):

That is because your php server gives response as a plain text not json. Look at the header `Content-Type: text/html`. Your server need to send header as a json with `Content-type: application/json`.

```
<?php
  $data = /** whatever you're serializing in array **/;
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($data);
```

---

Alternatively, if response is in `plain text`, you can parse that response to json in client side (javascript). Do this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax/index',
    data: $("#NewsletterSignup").serialize(), 
    success: function(data)
    {
        data = JSON.parse(data); 
        console.log(data);
        if (data.success == 'success') {
            console.log('successful');
        } else if(data.errors){
            console.log('error occurred');
        }
    }
});
```

Also you can expect json response in in jquery ajax, by using `dataType:'json'` option.

Comment: Best to add `;charset=UTF-8` to the header to specify the charset though